# Implementing Fixed-Width Sliding Windowing technique on sensor signal

Tags: matlab, signals, accelerometer, preprocessor, sliding-window

I am trying to replicate the signal pre processing done on this Data Set: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones#

"*The sensor signals (accelerometer and gyroscope) were pre-processed by applying noise filters and then sampled in fixed-width sliding windows of 2.56 sec and 50% overlap (128 readings/window)*"

I am trying to perform all my functionalities on Matlab and am stuck in trying to create a fixed width sliding window on my acceleration signals.

My main area is AI classification and have no background knowledge on signal preprocessing etc.. I've been trying to research etc for a long time but I cannot understand what I need to do to my signal.

I have signals which are produced at a 51.2 Sampling Frequency. Any help please on how I can generate a sampling window like the one done on the linked data set?

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate window length in number of samples and step=window-overlap and use this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190634/3344428 (you can clear unnecessary code for std, skewness etc.)

You should clarify window length, because you mentioned "128 readings/window", BUT if you use 2.56 sec window on 51.2 Hz signal, then window = 2.56*51.2 = 131 samples.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Re window length, is there an ideal way on how to calculate it? I only chose to follow the processing for that particular data set since mine is very similar and wanted to start testing with that. Though, in the previous study the 2.56 sec window is done on a 50Hz signal.
Regarding your code, what would I need to pass for the vars: x, window and step? And what you're doing there is that instead of creating a new data set with 128 readings per window, you are calculating the features for every window? Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe that is not about the sliding mean, but calculating a whole set of features from each window (i.e. mean value is a single feature, but there are many different features). Then you should seek the description on how to calculate each feature. I suppose that window length is chosen to be 2^7 for simple `fft` calculation, and you should use 128 readings as well (step = 64).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! So for x, I should pass my data set (e.g. the acceleration values over the x axis) and window would have a value of 128? Thanks again!